# WAMP LDAP Error

Tags: apache, ldap

I'm setting up WAMP server for LDAP validation.

I can start the apache server and phpinfo() shows LDAP is active.

But when I submit the user name and password, it shows 500 error.

The error description in apache log is:

> [Fri Mar 21 13:33:19.255265 2014] [ldap:error] [pid 8032:tid 1544]
>   (70023)This function has not been implemented on this platform:
>   AH01277: LDAP: Unable to add rebind cross reference entry. Out of
>   memory?

Can anyone help for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Blond's replay in this thread https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4851&view=next works for me.